# Seeking Sentinel L1C images (.SAFE) from 2015-2019 since no longer available on Copernicus Open Access Hub

Tags: usgs, sentinel-snap, sentinel, sentinel-hub

I am looking for Sentinel images from before 2019 in L1C quality and .SAFE format, as I want to correct them with sen2cor in SNAP to convert them to L2A quality.

Where can I find them now that they are offline & not available on the Copernicus Open Access Hub?

The Hub took them offline, and they are currently not requestable.

USGS Earthexplorer and Google Earth Engine only provide TIFFs and JPEGs.
So far I have only acquired JSONs from Amazon Web Services (connected to Sentinel Hub), but learning Python might make me able to acquire .SAFEs ..

Details:
I am making a monthly NDVI timeseries from december 2015 - 2020 of my research location in Bolivia. I use Sentinel 2 L2A images for this, and Google Earth Engine. Because there are no L2A images before 2019 I will have to process L1C images myself and upload them to GEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can still get Sentinel-2 L1C products here: https://peps.cnes.fr/rocket/

Select

- Collection: Sentinel-2 Single Tile"
- Processing Level: LEVEL1C